# Can the TV app on Macbooks play movie rentals in 4k?

Tags: macbook-pro, 4k, tv.app

I recently rented a movie from the TV app on my macbook, and I see that it's available in 4k.
Is 4k streaming playback supported on the TV app of my MacBook (I'm playing on a 4k external monitor)? How can I verify that the quality is indeed 4k?

I'm using a Macbook Pro, 15-inch, 2018 running Big Sur 11.1, connecting to the monitor via USB-C. On my monitor, it says that the current resolution is 3840x2160.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include the model & year of the MBP, OS you're using, and how you're connecting the external monitor (HDMI, USB-C, DisplayPort, etc).

Comment: Thanks for adding that info.  I know there's a 4k issue in 11.1 but I don't know if Apple fixed it yet.  I don't have a compatible device so I can't check this myself.